# how to break sentence after every dot (.) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a text like this

> Html is a Webbased language. For styling the webpage we have to use
>   the css. For this we have to write the css and include those files.

My expected out put like this:

> Html is a Webbased language.
>   For styling the webpage we have to use the css.
>   For this we have to write the css and include those files.

Comment: First of all, you have to add a question to your post and not just to your topic. Second, you can't achieve this by simply using html/css. You need js or php.

Comment: I'd like to add that it is impossible to select text nodes in CSS.

Comment: impossible without using javascript.

Comment: Tip: beware of ... used as … (&hellip;) ^^

Answer (score 12):

HTML ignores whitespace like newlines by default. You can handle it with CSS using the [white space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

```
div {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will tell the browser to preserve line endings in divs.

**EDIT**

But if your text does not have newlines after the full stops, you either have to do this with JavaScript as Hashem Qolami pointed out, or serverside using whatever language you have there.

See [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for how to do this client side.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this would be to use a list. Here's why:

1. HTML comes with it's own styling provided by H1-H6, p, strong, ul, ol etc. CSS merely adds visual styling.
2. You're obviously not breaking these lines for "the heck of it".
3. The output you desire is structured like a list.
4. The output would be read correctly regardless of the availability of visual styling (css) ex. screen readers etc.

Simple remove the list styling ex.

```
list-style-type: none;
```

The answer to your question is not "This can't be done", but you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. This is not a CSS issue, but a problem with your markup.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `pre` and make the text have actual line breaks after the periods

```
<pre>Html is a Webbased language.
For styling the webpage we have to use the css.
For this we have to write the css and include those files.</pre>
```

Or add html breaks with the `<br>` element

```html
Html is a Webbased language.<br/> For styling the webpage we have to use the css.<br/> For this we have to write the css and include those files.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question but people here says it's impossible in html/css etc and no one has contributed with the most simple answer.

Yes, it is possible. You first need to specify that there should be a new line in the string by using "\n".
Then as Jørgen R answered:
"HTML ignores whitespace like newlines by default. You can handle it with CSS using the white space property."

So to answer the question.
Change the string to the following:

```
Html is a Webbased language. \n For styling the webpage we have to use the css. \n For this we have to write the css and include those files.
```

and add to your css:

```
.div{
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not doable in CSS. There is no selector that allows you to select a portion of the text. You'll have to add the line breaks "manually" in javascript.